# angular jsonp yahoo finance symbolSuggest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp, yahoo-finance

I am trying to use [this](http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=Google&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback) following Yahoo Finance API call within my angular code. Angular [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) requires the callback parameter to be `JSON_CALLBACK`.

**Angular Callback Format**

```
var url = 'http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=Google&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
var dfd = $q.defer();
$http.jsonp(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log(data);
  dfd.resolve(data);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  dfd.reject(status);
});
```

However, it seems that this API call returns a 404 unless the callback is set specifically to `YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback`.

I can make the http request work like below by using that callback but then it is outside angular's scope. Is there any way to make this request in angular without polluting the global scope?

**Yahoo Callback Format**

```
var url = 'http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=Google&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback';
var dfd = $q.defer();
$http.jsonp(url).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    dfd.resolve(data);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    dfd.reject(status);
});
return dfd.promise;
};

// this has to be global for this to work! eww...
var YAHOO = {
    Finance: {
        SymbolSuggest: {
            ssCallback: function(r) {
                console.log(r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```